# How to set payment method in Woocommerce via PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to manually select payment method via PHP in a Woocommerce site.

Something like this:

`$payment_method = 'authorize_net_aim'`

Then when the customer hits checkout and sees the list payment options, the payment method that was set in PHP is auto-selected. The challenge is that woocommerce checkout.js runs ajax after the page is loaded. So any on-page stuff I've tried is overwritten.

I have reviewed the [WC_Payment_Gateway class](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Payment_Gateway.html) but don't see how to select a specific gateway using it's id (i.e. authorize_net_aim).

Answer (score -1):

The solution for this issue, i.e auto selecting a payment mode can be achieved using the following code.

`add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit','select_payment_mode_as_defined_here' );
function select_payment_mode_as_defined_here(){
    echo '<script>jQuery("#authorize_net_aim").prop("checked", true);</script>';
}`

Assumption is that 'authorize_net_aim' is the id of the radio option button.

I used this solution to select the PayPal method as default so set the id to '#payment_method_paypal' in jQuery() and it worked for me.

Lemme Know if it worked for you too. And whether this answer was useful or not.

Comment: woocommerce_review_order_before_submit is definitely good info. I will test and report back.

Comment: So this did not work. The reason is that Woocommerce runs it's Ajax update after all code is loaded. So it will overwrite any jquery. I need to set the payment method in WC sessions I think.

Comment: Another simple way is to set default payment gateway from the woocommerce settings in the dashboard. Let me know if this helps. Try this solution in a new session( Different browser/ incognito window) because it stores the default method in cart session.

Comment: The payment method is not predetermined. The visitor selects a payment method before woocommerce is initialized.